# if value changes in function, add into new array

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I`am filtering a search query by clicking at a checkbox. I have different check boxes. All uses the same function to add and remove my query build.
I am storing the values in a array and format them for my query build.

I'am using Elasticsearch for the query and angular7.

[image]

```
onChangeLocations(value: string, checked: boolean) {


    if (checked) {

      this.selectedLocations.push(value);

      this.selectedTopics.push({
        'match_phrase': { '134_facet_locations': value },
      });
      this.selectedTopics.push({
        'match_phrase': { '135_facet_locations': value },
      });
      this.selectedTopics.push({
        'match_phrase': { '136_facet_locations': value },
      });

    } else { 
this.selectedTopics = this.selectedTopics.filter((topic: any) => {
        return topic.match_phrase['134_facet_locations'] !== value;
      });
      this.selectedTopics = this.selectedTopics.filter((topic: any) => {
        return topic.match_phrase['135_facet_locations'] !== value;
      });
      this.selectedTopics = this.selectedTopics.filter((topic: any) => {
        return topic.match_phrase['136_facet_locations'] !== value;
      });


      this.selectedLocations = this.selectedLocations.filter((facet: any) => {
        return facet !== value;
      });

    }
 }
```

this is my Output that works for OR querys.

```
[
    {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                    "match_phrase": {
                        "134_facet_locations": "Deutschland"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match_phrase": {
                        "135_facet_locations": "Deutschland"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match_phrase": {
                        "136_facet_locations": "Deutschland"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match_phrase": {
                        "134_facet_locations": "Basel"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match_phrase": {
                        "135_facet_locations": "Basel"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match_phrase": {
                        "136_facet_locations": "Basel"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

I Need an Output for and querys that must look like this:

```
  {
    "should": [
        {
            "bool": {
                "should": [
                    {
                        "match_phrase": {
                            "134_facet_locations": "Basel"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "match_phrase": {
                            "135_facet_locations": "Basel"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "match_phrase": {
                            "136_facet_locations": "Basel"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "bool": {
                "should": [
                    {
                        "match_phrase": {
                            "134_facet_locations": "Deutschland"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "match_phrase": {
                            "135_facet_locations": "Deutschland"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "match_phrase": {
                            "136_facet_locations": "Deutschland"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }

    ]

}
```

I know how to add them once into an array. But i dont know how to build this complex json query in a good way.

Answer (score 0):

This is my suggestions for the answer. I must check if value changed. if it changed add topics to new "bool should" array. Something like this.